# Android Studio not opening the finder in order to open any project in mac

Tags: macos, android-studio, android-studio-chipmunk

**Android Studio version: Chipmunk 2021.2.1**
**Mac version: macOS Monterey version 12.4**

[image]

Whenever I click open in the above image in order to open any of my projects, android studio freezes completely, then I have to force quiet it in order to try again.

Im able to open all the projects which are in the recent menu list, and also able to create new projects as well. I tried to open one of the projects from the recent menu list and then tried to open other projects using the File-> open but it freeze again.

Any solutions to this?

Comment: This issue still occurs on my M1 MacBook (Monterey 12.4) and Android Studio 2021.2.1 Patch 1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a temporary solution, I have found the following way to open my other projects.

Open Terminal. 
Navigate to the project directory you want to open in android studio.
Enter the below command

```
open -a Android\ Studio Your_project_name
```

And that particular folder/project will get opened in android studio.

> I will update the answer once I get to know the fix of the actual
> problem, till then if anyone is facing the same issue you can use the
> above mention hack.

**Update**
With the new android studio update (2020.2.1) this issue was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue. Try to install **Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Beta 5**. For me it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and found that it was because Android Studio didn't have the correct permissions. I went to Settings > Security & Privacy > Files and Folders and gave permission for the Downloads Folder and it started working for me.