# Android Studio freezing when trying to open Finder on Mac

Tags: macos, android-studio

The same issue was reported here:

[Android Studio not opening the finder in order to open any project in mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72420737/android-studio-not-opening-the-finder-in-order-to-open-any-project-in-mac)

Basically, any time that Android Studio is trying to open up Finder, it freezes and I'm forced to force quit the app and open it again. This happens when going through "File -> Open..." or when creating a new project and selecting a different save location.

I am running Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 1.

The temporary solution given in the comments of the other post works well, but the update saying "With the new android studio update (2020.2.1) this issue was fixed" doesn't seem to be true for me, so I wanted to ask the question again. (As a note, I think he meant 2021.2.1)

I also uninstalled and reinstalled the App hoping that might fix it, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a permissions issue.

I started a new project (it does not require the Finder). Then I popped up the finder from File / Project Structure... dialog (pressing on ... of SDK Location) and that instance of Finder asked for permissions to access my drive.

After the permissions were granted the open project Finder started to work.

Comment: I ended up going into Settings > Security & Privacy > Files and Folders and found out that Android studio didn't have permission for Downloads Folder. Once I gave that permission, it works great! So, your solution didn't work directly for me, but it guided me to where I needed to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try to install the Preview version. For me **Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Beta 5** works fine. You can always check the fresh version here: https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/install-preview

Answer (score 0):

Adding value to *Valery M* [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73135324/2183717), the new Android Studio Dolphin 2021.3.1 fixed this problem for my MacMini running Catalina 10.15.7.

I updated using *Android Studio > Check for update*